# Adding custom duration to flutter_bloc's timer example

Tags: flutter, dart, state, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am learning `flutter_bloc` and did the timer example at https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertimertutorial?id=flutter-timer-tutorial

However the timer always resets to 60 seconds, so I wanted to the ability to set a custom initial duration.

My approach:

- Add a field `initialDuration` to [TimerState](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_timer/lib/timer/bloc/timer_state.dart) and all subclass constructors
- Add a `TimerNewDuration` event to [timer_event.dart](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_timer/lib/timer/bloc/timer_event.dart)
- Update [timer_bloc.dart](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_timer/lib/timer/bloc/timer_bloc.dart) to handle this with the following `emit` lines in each state handler:

```
constructor: super(TimerInitial(_defaultDuration)) # i.e. 60 seconds

_onNewDuration: emit(TimerInitial(event.duration))

_onStarted: emit(TimerRunInProgress(event.duration, state.initialDuration))

_onReset: emit(TimerInitial(state.initialDuration))

_onPaused: emit(TimerRunPause(state.duration, state.initialDuration))

_onTicked:     emit(event.duration > 0
        ? TimerRunInProgress(event.duration, state.initialDuration)
        : TimerRunComplete(state.initialDuration));
```

...and so on. However, this is a bit cumbersome: the timer state and the initial duration are not really related (except updating initial duration should reset the timer) and so I have to pass this value through every event handler in the BLoC.

If more state values are added, this would obviously get very messy.

Is there a more idiomatic way to handle this situation? Any github examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one state with copyWith(...) method:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class TimerState extends Equatable {
  const TimerState({
    this.isPause = false,
    this.isInProgress = false,
    this.isComplete = false,
    this.duration = 0,
  });

  final bool isPause;
  final bool isInProgress;
  final bool isComplete;
  final int duration;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [isPause, isInProgress, isComplete, duration];

  TimerState copyWith({
    bool? isPause,
    bool? isInProgress,
    bool? isComplete,
    int? duration,
  }) {
    return TimerState(
      isPause: isPause ?? this.isPause,
      isInProgress: isInProgress ?? this.isInProgress,
      isComplete: isComplete ?? this.isComplete,
      duration: duration ?? this.duration,
    );
  }
}
```

then your code will be something like:

```
constructor: super(TimerState(duration: _defaultDuration)) # i.e. 60 seconds

_onNewDuration: emit(state.copyWith(duration: event.duration))

_onStarted: emit(state.copyWith(isInProgress: true, isPaused: false))

_onReset: emit(TimerState(duration: _defaultDuration))

_onPaused: emit(state.copyWith(isPaused: true, isInProgress: false))

_onTicked: emit(state.copyWith(isCompleted: event.duration > 0);
```

p.s. TimerState could be sealed and for state complete could be used state:

```
final class TimerRunComplete extends TimerState {
  const TimerRunComplete();
}
```